# NSTimer v/s CFRunLoopTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, cfrunloop

My question is which one is better to use?

As **NSTimer** in turn uses the **CFRunLoopTimer** object.
What works better then other i got nothing about it on any site i googled for it but nothing, i got documents regarding both from **Apple's documents** but after reading them i doesn't understand or clear about `what to use NSTimer or CFRunLoopTimer?` 
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> CFRunLoopTimer is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSTimer.

Translation:

It doesn’t matter, so use `NSTimer` unless you’re knee deep in CF-code anyways or want to do funky stuff/associate non-object data with your timer.

Comment: Could you give me some hints as to what you need more info on?